# Wordpress keeps giving me following error : Warning: preg_match()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There is already one question almost related to my question but that answer did not help me as that answer includes lots of command line code. I am not so good into that.

> I also asked godaddy if it was related to the PHP or Mysql version,
>   but they could not help me. I have hosted my site on godaddy shared
>   server.

Whenever I upload any image or if I install any plugin say "meta-slider", it again start showing error.

Following is the frequent error I am getting in my admin control panel; also in the webpage.

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set
>   at offset 0 in
>   /home/santoshbhaiya/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/Misc.php on line
>   1926

My website URL is http://www.sanjaysinghintercollege.com
 control panel login is shashi/shashi

If I install any plugin it throws following error

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set
>   at offset 0 in
>   /home/santoshbhaiya/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 934

I have not put my question without research on stackoverflow or on google. Please help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is probably a really bad idea to publicly give out your login information. You might want to delete this post and resubmit without login information and also change your login information.

Comment: Its just a fresh setup. I have nothing to loose with this website at present. My working copy is in my localhost. When I hosted that to the live server I found the same issue. This is a fresh installation and if I get a solution then I will change the control panel login-ID and password also complete content would be changed. But thanks for suggession.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Godaddy` go to `cPanel` > `Select PHP version`

and change it to `PHP v5.5`

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask your host to update the PCRE version to 8.21 (minimum). That will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am sorry but but what is this PCRE? I am new into wordpress. Please help me.

Comment: Full form of PCRE is Perl Compatible Regular Extension. It's nothing to do with WordPress or any other PHP-based CMS or Frameworks. It's the engine that parses a regular expression used with preg_* functions in PHP. You need to ask your host (GoDadday in this case) to update it's version or you need to change the host to some other provider who has this issue already resolved. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am talking to godaddy at present. If it solves the issue I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: Godaddy support is telling that they can not upgrade PCRE to version 8. My server is designed for version 5. How to overcome from this and which hosting provider can give us PCRE 8  option for our website. Thanks a lot in advance. Please help me

Comment: Do they have any other server plan that supports PRCE 8.1? If so, go for it. Otherwise, look for BlueHost or Hostmonster. They are good to go.

Comment: I use Hostmonster and they have PCRE 8.32 enabled with PHP 5.4.30

Comment: I ran phpinfo() on your site and your PCRE version is 7.8. Is it possible that godaddy is confusing the PHP version 5.4 from the PCRE library version.

Comment: They have server with PCRE 5 only. They are ready to cancel the plan. I would look into your suggestions. I will check with Bluehost and Hostmonster. Thank you so much for saving my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MagentaCuda : You are right, I just checked phpinfo by running a file explicitly. Godaddy can not upgrade PCRE to 8 and asking to go for VPS which is beyond my budget. But thanks for your time. I am looking for the other server  suggested by anupam but this time I will confirm about this from their support executive and then go ahead. Thanks for everybody's time. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @ShashiRoy - I'm sure about Hostmonster. I use a shared hosting with PHP 5.4.30 and PCRE 8.32. See here http://axefinch.com/info.php. Search for PCRE and you will see the version. I will delete this page after 15 mins. Please confirm that you saw it.

Comment: @anupam : I just now checked it. Thanks for letting me know that your site is hosted on the shared server. I was worried about this also that, they should not ask me to go for VPS or dedicated server. Thank you so much. I just reviewed your file and found PCRE version8.32 2012-11-30 .

Comment: @ShashiRoy - Thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error message and also on GoDaddy.
I ran a simple phpinfo() in a test.php file and found that I had php ver 5.4.26 and pcre ver 7.8
I called up GoDaddy and the rep told me that my version of php was not up to date on my account and that she'd fix it. I thought she was full of it, but sure enough about 10 minutes later my site was up and running with php 5.4.29 and pcre 8.34.

Sometimes it pays to call, and be sure to get connected to the technical department which deals with website hosting. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have shared hosting with Godaddy. They told me to go to cPanel and change the PHP version from "native (5.4)" to just "5.4".

My Account -> Hosting -> cPanel -> Software/Services section -> Select PHP version.

It fixed the issue. I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Sorry, I visited back late only to extend my bad time. Its working like charm. Thank you so much. It has solved the issue. Very surprised to feel that Godaddy had no clue and idea to suggest me the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I called GoDaddy with the same issue and sent the agent a link to this thread.  He changed the PHP as the previous poster directed and it worked like a charm.  There must be a break on their side.